# Throughput calculation in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[image]Attached is the `Summary Report` for my tests.

Please help me understand how is the throughput value calculated by JMeter:
example the throughput of the very first line `53.1/min`, how was this figure calculated by JMeter with which formula.

Also, wanted to know how are the throughput values in the subsequent test divided into mins or secs. example the 2nd line has a throughput `1.6/sec`, so how does JMeter calculate this throughput values based on the time units ?

Tried many websites on the net and have got a common reply that the throughput is the number of requests per unit of time (seconds, minutes, hours) that are sent to your server during the test. But that didn't apply to the results I see in my graph the way it was explained straight forward.

Answer (score 20):

[Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) defines Throughput as

> requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>   The formula is: **Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)**.

So in your case you had 1 request, which took 1129ms, so

```
Throughput = 1 / 1129ms = 0.00088573959/ms 
           = 0.00088573959 * 1000/sec = 0.88573959/sec 
           = 0.88573959 * 60/min = 53.1443754/min, rounded to 53.1/min
```

For 1 request total time (or elapsed time) is the same as the time of this single operation. For requests executed multiple times, it would be equal to

```
Throughput = (number of requests) / (average * number of requests) = 1 / average
```

For instance if you take the last line in your screenshot (with 21 requests), it has an average of 695, so throughput is:

```
 Throughput = 1 / 695ms = 0.0014388489/ms = 1.4388489/sec, rounded to 1.4/sec
```

In terms of units (sec/min/hour), Summary report does this:

- By default it displays throughput in seconds
- But if throughput in seconds < 1.0, it will convert it to minutes
- If it's still < 1.0, it will convert it to hours
- It rounds the value to 1 decimal digit afterwards.

This is why some values are displayed in sec, some in min, and some could be in hours. Some may even have value 0.0, which basically means that throughput was < 0.04

Comment: Formula `1 / average` works for one thread. How will it be changed for several threads?

Comment: @olyv average is not per thread, it's across all threads. So one threads or many, the formula is the same

Answer (score 1):

I have been messing with this for a while and here is what I had to do into order for my numbers to match what jmeter says

Loop through my lines in the csv file, gather the LOWEST start time for each of the labels you have, also grab the HIGHEST (timestamp + elapsed time)
Calculate the difference between those in seconds
then do number of samples / the difference

So in excel, the easiest way to do it is get the csv file and add a column for timestamp + elapsed
First sort the block by the timestamp - lowest to highest then fine the first instance of each label and grab that time
Then sort by your new column highest to lowest and grab the first time again for each label

For each label then gather both of these times in a new sheet
A would be the label
B would be the start time
C would be the endtime+elapsed time
D would then be (C-B)*1000 (diff in seconds)
E would then be the number of samples for each label
F would be E/D (samples per second)
G would be F*60 (samples per minute)