# based on Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time), I got two different throughput numbers

Tags: jmeter, throughput

Please look at the output of JMeter run:

```
TestA   20  0   0.00%   45423.30    26988   62228   60189.40    62130.85    62228.00    0.24    1.21    3.07

TestB   20  0   0.00%   245530.50   225405  260410  259775.40   260401.20   260410.00   0.06    0.29    0.51
```

It is all from the same test run (same period), and one throughput is 0.24 and the other is 0.06.  Something wrong with JMeter?

Thanks for the input,

John

Comment: The format is gone.  Basically, it is TestA and TestB are all with 20 samplers in the same test duration, but throughput is 0.06 and 0.24 respectively.

Comment: CHeck this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528411/throughput-calculation-in-jmeter/39535967#39535967

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you're using numbers from [JMeter Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) therefore we're looking at:

```
Label | #Samples| KO| %Errors| Average |Min    |Max    |90%      |95%       |99%      |Throughput | Received |Sent  

TestA | 20      | 0 | 0.00%  | 45423.30| 26988 | 62228 |60189.40 | 62130.85 |62228.00 | 0.24      | 1.21     |  3.07

TestB | 20      | 0 |0.00%   |245530.50| 225405| 260410|259775.40| 260401.20|260410.00| 0.06      |0.29      | 0.51
```

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

Looking into **Average** column you have `45` seconds of average response time for `Test A` and `245` seconds for `Test B`. It means that `Test B` was **6x times longer** than the `Test A` therefore you have 6x times lower Throughput.

So I would recommend looking into server-side logs, version control system commits, [APM tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management), [profiling tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)), [JMeter PerfMon Plugin results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), etc. in order to identify why response time for `Test B` became 6x times worse than for `Test A`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.  But the formula does not consider any of these for throughput, so is it wrong?