# Jmeter Transactions Per Second do not represent actual requests processed in second

Tags: jmeter, horizontal-scaling

I am in confusion here for what is the right parameter to find how many requests my service can handle in a sec..
Eg: According to docs & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528411/throughput-calculation-in-jmeter/39535967) post TPS(transactions/sec) is calculated based on elapsed time of the request which seems to be fair when you have one service instance. Eg: My elapsed time is 1 second so my tps is 1 which makes sense, but the calculations fail when i have 3 service instance(H-Scaled) though the elapsed time remains the same but now i can process 3 concurrent requests in that same second which should ideally read back as 3 tps but it doesnt

Q:Then what is the right parameter in jmeter report to check for this ? or is my theory wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

And **request** is something produced by JMeter's [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

If you're doing some scalability testing you can measure it as follows:

1. Run a [stress test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing) with 1 service instance, i.e. start with 1 user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking at TPS. At some point you will reach the stage where increasing the number of users won't result in increased TPS due to some [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing). Measure the number of users and the TPS just before the bottleneck hits you.
2. Re-run your test with 3 service instances, you should see that the number of users and TPS before the bottleneck is higher now.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work that way, or i was not able to emulate this in right way, I have simple node service, docker file, docker compose here https://github.com/LRagji/redis-lsm-timeseries/tree/H-scalling  Findings: When i run this service with single instance and 1000 users it resonates to 0.7k TPS beyond this number resource bottle neck but when i hit same service with lower users TPS falls below and multiple instance also donot help

Comment: What i mean is 
700TPS= Resource Limit, so if i run 300users it should show me full 300TPS but it doesn't as the time part in formulae comes into play

Comment: It should "work this way", if it doesn't - the "bottleneck" is somewhere else, i.e. your system doesn't have sufficient amount of resources in terms of CPU, RAM, etc, double check that both JMeter and system under test have enough headroom to operate using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test). Also running JMeter and the system under test on same machine is not the best idea due to potential [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Comment: Its not a resource bottle neck i can guarantee that cause its just doing delayed response and machine has sufficient head room also, I need to frame the question in better way i guess but for now i can accept yours as answer...